# Can I transit to Madrid on my single entry Schengen Visa?

Tags: visas, schengen, transit, italy, spain

I originally received my Schengen Visa for my upcoming 11 days trip to Italy, however I have 6 hours layover in Madrid and was planning to checkout madrid during that time. I just realized that they only granted me single entry and now I am worried that if I visit Madrid during my transit, Italian immigration can resufe my entry when i get there.

Comment: If your flight is from Madrid to Italy, you will pass immigration in Madrid anyway, not in Italy.

Comment: fkariem, you should post that as an answer. Tara, he's correct - your first entry into the EU is all you need. Once you're inside the EU, your Schengen visa allows you to travel freely within the Schengen Area.

Comment: @fkraiem, yes, it's an answer.  Suggest you write it up before somebody snipes it.

Comment: You might struggle with the timing abit, since most European airports require you to be present 2 hours in advance, and you also need about an hour to get to and from downtown Madrid. 3 hours is not that much to visit Madrid.

Comment: I don't know a European airport that *requires* you to be present two hours in advance for a European flight - the actual safe minimum time would depend on the airport though, and I don't know Madrid.

Comment: @NateKerkhofs: At least in Germany - and I doubt it's too different in other European places -, the times are usually said to be *one* hour in advance for domestic flights, two hours for international flights, and three hours for flights to the U.S. And those are the *recommended* times for the *initial* leg, i.e. including check-in and/or baggage drop-off, which often are irrelevant for subsequent legs.

Comment: Even if it's only 1 hour needed, 4 hours is still not that much if you don't want to get overly rushed. I might have been confused with my 2 hours from when I flew from Belgium to Spain once a year, which last was 4 years ago by now. We always arrived 2 hours in advance in Brussels Airport.

Answer (score 19):

As a general principle, the entire Schengen area is considered one country for immigration purposes. This means in particular that a flight between two Schengen countries (in your case, Spain and Italy) is considered a domestic flight and there is no immigration control before or after the flight.

Hence, in your case you will enter the Schengen area and pass immigration when you arrive in Madrid, regardless of whether you exit the airport or not. There will be no immigration control in Italy at all.